# There is a metric on N that is not equivalent to the discrete metric

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Show that there is a metric on N that is not equivalent to the discrete metric. Any hint or answer would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: it suffices to find a *countably infinite* metric space $(X, d')$ with a non-discrete metric. Then there will be a bijection $\phi : \Bbb{N} \to X$, and you can define your metric on $\Bbb{N}$ by $d(m, n) = d'(\phi(m), \phi(n))$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$ be a bijection. Define $d(n,m)=| f(n)-f(m)|$.